# Не срабатывает метод click() в pywinauto

Tags: python, qt, pywinauto

Пытаюсь автоматизировать приложение на Qt.
Python 3.7.4, pywinauto 0.6.7

```
from pywinauto import Application

app = Application(backend="uia").start(r'application.exe')
dialog = app.window(title_re="MyApplication")
contacts_btn = dialog.window(title_re="\u041A\u043E\u043D\u0442\u0430\u043A\u0442\u044B", control_type="Button")
contacts_btn.print_control_identifiers()
contacts_btn.click()
```

Данный код выводит следующее:

```
Control Identifiers:

Button - 'Контакты'    (L139, T392, R219, B454)
['КонтактыButton', 'Button', 'Контакты', 'Контакты0', 'Контакты1']
child_window(title="Контакты", control_type="Button")
   |
   | Static - 'Контакты'    (L151, T431, R207, B447)
   | ['КонтактыStatic', 'Static', 'Контакты2']
   | child_window(title="Контакты", control_type="Text")
```

Но, почему-то, метод `contacts_btn.click()` не срабатывает.
В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ найден [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46925321/10615146):

вместо

```
contacts_btn.click()
```

в данном случае необходимо использовать

```
contacts_btn.click_input()
```

Comment: Всё верно. Иногда элементы на стороне приложения не полностью реализуют UI Automation provider. Для Qt это особенно часто, но хотя бы иерархия более-менее предоставляется.

Comment: Можно, кстати, свой собственный ответ заакцептить. Размер репутации не важен.